# Installed programs in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, installed-programs

I am a new user of Ubuntu Is there a way to see all installed programs in Ubuntu 14.04 and also install/uninstall programs from there, like in windows there is programs and features in control panel.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Software Center has a tab for *Installed* programs:

[image]

The Software Center being the software center, you can add or remove programs from it.